# .js for loop is returning two of each value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop that returns values that double each time (1,2,4,8,16...) this code works but returns each value twice (2,2,4,4,8,8,16,16...) any idea what I am missing?

```
dub = function(howMany){
for(i = 1, y = 1, z = ''; z < howMany ; i = y, y = x, z ++ ){
    x = i * 2;
    console.log(x);
}};dub(20);
```

Comment: It's unclear why you are using this convoluted method. Can't you just do `i = i * 2` inside your loop?

Comment: Why do you use so many different variables? And why intermingle them? Use one variable for one purpose only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) function

```
dub = function (howMany) {
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        console.log(Math.pow(2, i))
    }
};
dub(20);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zgyybz1u/)

---

If you don't want to use Math.pow(), you can use 2 variables, 1 as counter and another as the multiplier like

```
dub = function (howMany) {
    for (var i = 0, x = 1; i < howMany; i++, x *= 2) {
        console.log(x);
    }
};
dub(20);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zgyybz1u/4/)

---

Also note as suggested by @naomik below, you need to declare all the variables used in the loop as local scoped, else in can modify a variable with the same in another scope(like global or closure scope)

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted, because this answer works, and it's very simple. I don't know why someone would *not* want to use the `Math.pow` method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've overcomplicated the for loop:

```
function dub(howMany) {
    for(var i = 1, y = 1;i<=howMany;i++, y+=y) {
        console.log(y);
    }
}
```

I'm not clear on the increment/decrement portion of the for loop or why you assigned an empty string to `z` in the initialization. The reason your loop was returning duplicates is found by walking through the loop with the variable states in mind.

```
Iteration 01 - i:1 x:0 y:1 z: <empty string>
Iteration 02 - i:1 x:2 y:2 z: 1
Iteration 03 - i:2 x:2 y:2 z: 2
Iteration 04 - i:2 x:4 y:4 z: 3
Iteration 05 - i:4 x:4 y:4 z: 4
Iteration 06 - i:4 x:8 y:8 z: 5
Iteration 07 - i:8 x:8 y:8 z: 6
Iteration 08 - i:8 x:16 y:16 z: 7
Iteration 09 - i:16 x:16 y:16 z: 8
Iteration 10 - i:16 x:32 y:32 z: 9
```

Note that the way your back-assigning `y` to `i` then `x` to `y` and so forth is unnecessary. Hopefully I've answered your question as perhaps you had other requirements not shared that required chaining those values like that, but not just for creating a doubling loop as described.

Here's a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f39jd848/

Comment: In the first iteration, `z` is actually `0`; `var z = ''; z++; // 0`. Otherwise, very good write-up tho.

Comment: Yes, it's interpreted as zero, but if passed to console.log (as in the list above, it's empty (I typed in <empty string> for clarity). Thanks!

Comment: Seth, no I mean he's using `for(i = 1, y = 1, z = '' ...` as the init for his for loop. `z` starts as a literal empty string... You were right the first time, just that `z` is `0` for the second iteration, `1` for the third, and so on.

Comment: I see. The output above (the Iteration XX lines) is actual output from OP's function (except where I typed '<empty string>')

Answer (score -2):

If you put this at the top of your for loop, it'll skip the second iteration:

```
if (z%2==1) continue;
```

Comment: op's code is not working because he's passing the old value of x into y and the old value of y into i, so the loop takes two iterations before i changes to x*2. I have no idea what your code fixes.

Comment: still wrong. it'll need to be after the x assignment and before console.log to achieve OP's intended function. Not to mention it's a convoluted fix to convoluted code.. just let it go